# jQuery (window).risize() isn't working as expected

Tags: jquery, browser

The problem I'm having is that I need this jQuery code to make a color coded list broken down into sections for smaller devices. For larger devices the code should just be in a colored list. Now I seemingly got this working alright. The problem is that the jQuery formatting for the larger colored list isn't be applied between the approximate pixels 619 and 765. It needs to display one way for a width of less than 600 pixels and another way for greater than 600 pixels. Any insight into this problem will be greatly appreciated. I apologize for the sloppy syntax but I'm just trying to hurry and make this pan out.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript">
        $(function(){
            var set = '';
        // jqUpdateLow to change with the width of the screen
        function jqUpdateLow(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        var x = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var text;
        if(width < 599 && jqUpdateLow.counter != 1)
        {
            jqUpdateLow.counter = 1;
            jqUpdateHigh.counter = 1;
            var set = 1;
            // $('body').append(" First conditional clause exectued ");

        $('#indiv_slots,#indiv_head').each(function(indexm,stack) {
        $(stack).css('margin-top','50px');
        });
            $('#indiv_slots div,#indiv_head div').each(function(index,element) {
        // Switch to set the the color and text for each element of the list    
        switch(count)
        {
        case 0:
        color = "#7FDBFF"; // aqua
        text = "ID";
        break;
        case 1:
        color = "#E9967A"; // dark salmon
        text = "Available";
        break;
        case 2:
        color = "#FF4136"; // red
        text = "Type";
        break;
        case 3:
        color = "#DDDDDD"; // silver
        text = "Cat";
        break;
        case 4:
        color = "#01FF70"; // lime
        text = "Dog";
        break;
        case 5:
        color = "#39CCCC"; // teal
        text = "Rent";
        break;
        case 6:
        color = "#FF851B"; // orange
        text = "State";
        break;
        case 7:
        color = "#3D9970"; // olive
        text = "Bedrooms";
        break;
        }   
            $(element).css("background-color",color);
            count++;
            if(count == 8) { count = 0;}
            if(index > 7)
            {
                $(element).prepend('<span class="prepended">' + text + ':' + '</span>');
            }
        });

        }
        };
        function jqUpdateHigh()
        { 
        var width = $(window).width();
        var x = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var text;
        if(width > 601 && jqUpdateHigh.counter != 0)
        {
            jqUpdateHigh.counter = 0;
            jqUpdateLow.counter = 0;
            // Removes prepended text.
            $('.prepended').remove();
            $('#indiv_slots div,#indiv_head div').each(function(indexb,elementb) {
            $(elementb).css("background-color","");
            $(elementb).css("opacity","");
            });
            // $('body').append(" Second conditional clause exectued ");
            $('#indiv_slots,#indiv_head').each(function(indexx,elementx) {
            $(elementx).css('margin-top','');
            switch(indexx)
            {
            case 0:
            color = "#7FDBFF"; // aqua
            break;
            case 1:
            color = "#E9967A"; // dark salmon
            break;
            case 2:
            color = "#FF4136"; // red
            break;
            case 3:
            color = "#DDDDDD"; // silver
            break;
            case 4:
            color = "#01FF70"; // lime
            break;
            case 5:
            color = "#E9967A"; // dark salmon
            }
            $(elementx).css('background-color',color);
            });
        }
        };
        $('.starter-template .row').css('background-color','');
        jqUpdateLow();
        jqUpdateHigh();
        $(window).resize(function() {
        jqUpdateLow();
        jqUpdateHigh();
        });
        });
```

Comment: I should also mention that it looks exactly how it is except for those pixel ranges I gave. Everything is working, it just has a glitch in it.

Comment: You need to rephrase that. I dont know what you have, whats the problem and how should it work, and me and probably many people who can help you will just skip this question.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use media queries, but to answer your question, try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 600){  
        console.log("do something here, such adding a CSS Class");
    }   
});
```